# neural network feature strength in Python

Tags: python-2.7, deep-learning, keras

I am using Keras in python to train a neural network model using DNN. I want to figure out the strength of each feature that is being applied while training the model. From the Ian Goodfellow book on Deep Learning I learned that it is possible for an NN. But how? Can anyone help me on that?

Comment: That's a good question. Can you please specify in the question what do you mean by "feature strength" (just to avoid ambiguity)?

Comment: By Feature strength I mean how much weight is applied to each Feature while determining the Network

Comment: @FalconUA This is not a good question at all, even less for Stack Overflow. Please read [Do pure "machine learning" questions belong on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291009/1233251) and [Which Stack Exchange website for machine learning and computational algorithms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130524/282465).